# Abbreviations possible in zsh?

Tags: zsh

Here is a simple thing I want to achieve. In the later part of a command, I want to use an abbreviation.

Say, I want to `ls ~/Documents` but I just enter `ls Docs` and it expands 'Docs' to '~/Documents'

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "global" aliases in zsh:

```
alias -g Docs=~/Documents
```

Then `ls Docs` will act like `ls ~/Documents`.
Global aliases expand any word in a command line, not just the first, so any use of `Docs` as an argument will be affected (unless quoted).

Answer (score 0):

Define your abbreviation as a variable like

```
Docs="~/Documents"
```

and call it like so:

```
ls $Docs
```

Despite that's not what you want it's worth mentioning: A full **command including options and arguments** can be abbreviated using `alias`, e.g.

```
alias 'Docs'='ls -l ~/Documents'
```